# Alternating string of characters and digits

Tags: java, string, queue, character, alternating

I was given this problem to solve. I have only the slightest idea on how it should be implemented, and I'm all too new with programming and stuffs, and would love to hear your comments on this.

Say given a string in the form "abc1234defgh567jk89", and I must create a new string "a1b2c3d5e6f7j8k9".

Note that there are corresponding [digits] & [characters] group and since there may be more of one type over the other, the output has only matching sequence and ignore extra digits or characters in this case '4' & 'g' & 'h'.

I know I will have to use 2 sets of **queues** to store both types of elements, but I do not know how else to proceed from here.

Would appreciate if you could share a pseudocode or a Java(prefably) version, since I am learning thru this language now.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try already? You will find better answers if the people see you did some effort to achieve what do you need.

Comment: Ah ic.. Ok, I'll write a formal code soon. But what I have in mind now is the usage of is_empty() to check if the queues have items in them, and it has to alternate somehow between checking the 2.

Comment: Take a look to String.replaceAll method as suggested to get the separated Strings and String.toCharArray to get an array of characters. Then iterate both char arrays to get the compossed String.

Comment: ok, so you're suggesting that I break it down to a character array? but then how do you explain the '4', 'g' & 'h' exclusion?

Comment: @kent See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pseudocode:

```
Queue letterQueue;
Queue numberQueue;

for (every character in the string) {
    if (it's a letter) {
        if (numberQueue is not empty) {
            add the letters alternating into the buffer (stringbuilder), and purge buffers
        }
        add newest letter to letterqueue
    }
    if (it's a number) {
        add newest letter to numberqueue
    }
}
add any remaining unprocessed letters to the queue (this will happen most of the time)

return contents of string buffer
```

You will need:

- [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), probably a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
- [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [String.toCharArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)
- [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

### Code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class StringTest {
    private static String str ="abc1234defgh567jk89";
    
    private static String reorganize(String str) {
        Queue<Character> letterQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Character> numberQueue = new LinkedList<>();
            
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
                if (!numberQueue.isEmpty()) processQueues(letterQueue, numberQueue, s);
                letterQueue.offer(c);
            } else if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                numberQueue.offer(c);
            }
        }
    
        processQueues(letterQueue, numberQueue, s);

        return s.toString();
    }
    
    private static void processQueues(Queue<Character> letterQueue, Queue<Character> numberQueue, StringBuilder s) {
        while(!letterQueue.isEmpty() && !numberQueue.isEmpty()) {
            s.append(letterQueue.poll());
            s.append(numberQueue.poll());
        }
        letterQueue.clear();
        numberQueue.clear();
    }
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(reorganize(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, so implement the Queues through a Linkedlist? but according to you suggested way, doesn't it produce [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k] & [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. The first has 10 elements while the second has just 9. wont this leave out 'k' only?

Comment: sorry sorry for the trouble. btw i didn't cast that downvote. ppl shd appriecate your kind gesture to help :(

Comment: @kent my code didn't give the right answer. I fixed it just now though

Comment: ok, anyway what does this do "Runner.main(StringTest.class, new String[0]);" in the main method?

Comment: sure.. let me see if I've understood the code correctly. you used an enhanced for loop to cycle thru the elements in a char[] and if it is in 'num_mode', you call processQueue(), otherwise it gets added into the letterQueue and same for num. the flag gets updated accordingly. and u use s a stringbuilder to hold the temp value before printing it at the end. anw, this is my first time coming across stringbuilder ;)

Comment: @kent I removed the `numberMode` variable as it's not needed, all you have to do is check that `numberQueue` is not empty in order to process the queues. It should be easier to follow now

Answer (score 0):

See this hint:

```
String str = "abc1234defgh567jk89";
String c = str.replaceAll("\\d", "");  // to store characters
String d = str.replaceAll("\\D", ""); // to store digits
```

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abc1234defgh567jk89";
    String c = str.replaceAll("\\d", "");
    String d = str.replaceAll("\\D", "");
    String result = "";
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    int max = Math.max(c.length(), d.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (j++ < c.length())
            result = result + c.charAt(i);
        if (k++ < d.length())
            result = result + d.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8j9k
```

Comment: thanks! so is 'd' a regex for lowercase characters? sorry i'm too new to all these.

Comment: @kent [See here for Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: great.. but '4', 'g' 'h' and the order is a little different from the expected output. Thanks a lot! Still, I've learnt something new about the replaceAll().

Comment: @kent You want one character followed by one digit...yes?

Comment: Just giving the code to the OP doesn't help him very much to do any effort next time. In this case I think general guides or advices would be a better approach. He is learning so give him some advices and let him make mistakes and learn from himself is preferable and if he has some specific question then help him with a little piece of code. IMHO.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. '4', 'g' and 'h' should not be printed.